# question about logs

Tags: linux, logs

So just a little bit of background, i have a linux machine that generally has been stable, but recently its been rebooting by itself, or just freezing up (and maybe then rebooting), and when i go and look at the logs to try and figure out what happened, at the time it happened, all that is in the logs is some number of "^@" (usually multiple lines of these) is there a way to figure out what is causing this? as those lines are less then helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Which of the logs of a modern Linux system? Which Linux distro are you using? (I ask because that might have effect on the tools you have at hand to solve/work around the problem) and, as I agree with Jeff, this screams "interrupted write operation on a slow storage medium with a file system that falls at keeping a log": what kind of storage medium is this on, and what is the file system that the log resides on, and if different, the / file system?

Comment: If it reboots after freezing, I would look to the watchdog timer. If it does not receive a keepalive packet it may force a reboot. In which case I would suspect 1 of 2 reasons, overloaded system or hardware failure. I would try disabling it and see if it just locks up until the big red button it hit.